# two dispatchertimer events at the same time?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

i have a wpf app that is updating date/time in one dispatchertimer, another is for a mp3 player timer that tracks time and slidebar for playing time.  is it possible to have 2 dispatchertimer's running?

that's `dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);`
and `dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mp3Timer_Tick);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

What you are doing is something different: You are trying to attach *two* event handlers to *one* DispatcherTimer. Don't do that. If you want two timers for different purposes (and with different timeouts), use *two* DispatcherTimer objects:

```
dateTimeTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dateTimeTimer_Tick); 
mp3Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(mp3Timer_Tick);
```

Then you can do something like...

```
mp3Timer.Stop();
```

...when the music stops playing, and it won't affect the `dateTimeTimer`.